# SIMPER results interpretation

Tags: r, ecology, vegan

I am doing a SIMPER analysis(R::vegan) where I want to determine which species are contributing the most to differences between thermo groups-warm and cold.
(I am count data that is separated by years. The years are grouped as either warm affiliated years or cold affiliated years--> the overall goal would be to see if warmer years are impacting biodiversity of the study location).

I am new to SIMPER and only somewhat understand how the results are to be interpreted (the basics of what each output is). For example, if Spec1 has the highest average species contribution but its p value isn't considered significant, how is this treated for results? Are there additional tests to follow SIMPER results with too that might help explain? I planned on computing PERMANOVA and have alpha diversity metrics on top of this as well.

Comment: Without a reproducible example or even more details on the question, it can't be answered

Comment: You can add a permutation test to the SIMPER analysis, and then do a Krushkal-Wallis test to test for statistical significance   see this tutorial:  https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/343284_cbadd2f3b7cd42f3aced2d3f42dc6d33.html#otus_that_differ_by

Comment: Please read the vegan::simper help page (?simper).